# What's the difference between AnnotationReader & SimpleAnnotationReader?

Tags: doctrine-orm

The [Doctrine Common annotations library](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html) defines 2 annotation readers that both implement the `Reader` interface:

- `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader`
- `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\SimpleAnnotationReader`

Anyone knows the difference between them?

The only hint I have is the docblock on `SimpleAnnotationReader`:

> This annotation reader is intended to be used in projects where you have
>   full-control over all annotations that are available.

Comment: After "orm:convert-mapping  --from-database annotation ./src/"; You should use AnnotationReader instead of SimpleAnnotationReader.
Because “orm:generate-entities ./src/ –generate-annotations=true” will throw an error
“no metadata classes to process.”
To handle this error use “$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode, NULL, NULL, $useSimpleReader = false);” in your “bootstrap.php”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the single most important difference between the two is explained [here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/462173ad71ae63cd9877e1e642f7968ed1f9971b/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php#L140-L141) in the Doctrine code: `SimpleAnnotationDriver` can handle non-imported annotations (given a default namespace), while `AnnotationReader` needs a properly imported annotation.

Comment: never link to a branch. that's not a permalink.

Answer (score 7):

- The **AnnotationReader** will try to read ALL annotations.

You can give it a list of excluded annotations like `@param` and `@return` to ignore. It can be a problem since it's hard to exclude any possible annotation that you don't want.

- The **SimpleAnnotationReader** can load only the annotations you register to it.

Code example:

```
AnnotationRegistry::registerAutoloadNamespace('My\Annotation', 'dir/');
$this->annotationReader = new SimpleAnnotationReader();
$this->annotationReader->addNamespace('My\Annotation');
```

I will not get errors if there is any unknown annotation in the file.

There's one catch though: if the user makes a typo in the annotation name, then the reader will silently ignore it :(

---

Source: while developing PHP-DI, I tested both. The `SimpleAnnotationReader` is better for me because I want it to only read my `@Inject` annotation. When using `AnnotationReader`, I got errors if there was any unknown annotation in the file (for example `@expectedException` from PHPUnit).

See also [this issue](https://github.com/mnapoli/PHP-DI/issues/124).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the simple Annotation reader will try to read ALL annotations he will see in the doc blocks, while the AnnotationReader can handle a list of annotations to ignore (like @param, or @return).

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, this is an important distinction between the two classes.